# Arraylist with Multi Dimentional for loops

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, arraylist

Friends I have a serious issue at present and Honestly I have no idea as to why this isn't working as expected. I am more a custom to C# than VB can anyone help with the following Code Example

Please note that the String is passed from other classes and cannot be altered

```
The string arrL = "Someone#Something,200,First,50.00,60,Second,60.00,20,Third,70.00,120"
```

E.G where "Someone" is User, "Something" is an ID, "200" is Totaltime then frequency name "First" then frequency of "50.00" then its Time to run e.g 60 seconds. then next Item and so on.

```
 Dim Sequence As New ArrayList
    Sequence.AddRange(arrL.Split(","))

    If Sequence.Count > 0 Then
        RunFreq.ClientName = Sequence(0).ToString.Split("#")(0)
        RunFreq.ClientProgramName = Sequence(0).ToString.Split("#")(1)
        RunFreq.ClientProtocolTotalTime = Sequence(1).ToString

        For i As Integer = 2 To Sequence.Count - 1
            Dim g() = Sequence(i).ToString().Split(",")
            Dim b As New ClassWave.ClassFrequency
            b.Name = g(0) 'Here i get a Value 
            b.Frequency = CDbl(g(1)) '< HERE I get Index was outside the bounds of the array.
            b.Time = CInt(g(2)) ' Same here Index was outside the bounds of the array.                

        Next
    End If
```

I get Index Outside Bounds on g(1) and g(2) instead of 50.00 and 60. Any Ideas?

Comment: `Sequence` already split the string by `","`, so `g` will have only one element after you try to split it again.  You also need to turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: Ah yes. Makes sense but now. how can I go about achieving the desired results. VB and I are in a disagreement ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminaries: You should turn on `Option Strict`, and consider using a `List(of String)` in place of the `ArrayList`.

Your second line, splits the string by `","` into `Sequence`, so there is no need to split it again - you get the error because they cant be split further (and you didnt check the count).  This works:

```
Dim arrl As String = "Someone#Something,200,First,50.00,60,Second,60.00,20,Third,70.00,120"

Dim Sequence As New ArrayList
Sequence.AddRange(arrl.Split(","c))

Dim a, b, c As String

If Sequence.Count > 0 Then
    a = Sequence(0).ToString.Split("#"c)(0)
    b = Sequence(0).ToString.Split("#"c)(1)
    c = Sequence(1).ToString
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", a, b, c)

    For i As Integer = 2 To Sequence.Count - 1 Step 3

        a = Sequence(i + 0).ToString            
        b = Sequence(i + 1).ToString            
        c = Sequence(i + 2).ToString            

        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", a, b, c)
    Next
End If
```

You could also use this for the split:

```
Sequence.AddRange(arrl.Split("#"c, ","c))
```

This would create 12 elements in the ArrayList, but since the first 3 parts go elsewhere, that doesnt have as much value.

Output:

> Someone - Something - 200
>   First - 50.00 - 60
>   Second - 60.00 - 20
>   Third - 70.00 - 120

Note that `.ToString()` is required when fetching from the ArrayList because it is not typed - it only ever contains Object.  A `List(of String)` would store the parts as string.

Comment: Learn something new each day. Thank you so much **Plutonix** Your solution is right on the money. Been bashing my head against a wall of the better part of a week on this. thank again its much appreciated !

Comment: If you cannot absolutely depend on the string being in the right format, you might want to check the count of the split results so you dont run out of data if/when it fails...or add a Try/Catch

Comment: At some point I remember i did check the count of the array, but with trying so many different things I got lost fairly Quickly. Nevertheless sound advice thanks. Will keep that in mind moving forward.